# UnityEngine.VR.WSA.WebCam Not Found During Build

Tags: unity-game-engine, webcam, unityscript, video-capture

I tried to use Unity VideoCapture API, which is located inside UnityEngine.VR.WSA.WebCam namespace. In Editor mode I can play the scene without getting any error, but when I tried to build it for Windows and/or Mac, I got error that said UnityEngine.VR.WSA.WebCam namespace not found...

What is wrong? FYI, I use Unity 5.6... Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 1):

The library has been updated. Include the following namespace in your project:

```
UnityEngine.XR.WSA.WebCam;
```

Also, make sure that the capabilities are activated in the Publishing section for project Player settings - valid for Unity 2017.3

If you are using Unity 5.x, these settings will be available under the MR Toolkit settings.